# How to retrieve the data from the POST in NODE JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, localhost

Here is my HTML form

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" ng-submit="loginuser()">
                    <input type="email" ng-model="user.username" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required>
                    <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" required>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

and my app.js is

```
function navbarformcontroller($scope,$http){
    $scope.user = {};

    $scope.loginuser = function(){
        console.log('entered');
        $http({
            method : 'POST' ,
            url : 'http://localhost:3000/login',
            data : $scope.user
        })
            .success(function(data){
                alert(data);
            })
            .error(function(data, status){
                alert(data + " " + status + 'x');
            })
    };
}
```

and on my server side is node js is

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    req.render('login',{username : req.username, password : req.password});
    res.send('success');
    log(username + "   " + password);
});
```

and error details are in client console is

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:3000/login`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://localhost:63342`' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Don't run your application on two different ports, or you become a victim of the [SOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)…

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is restricting access to a different domain. You are using localhost however different ports thats why your domain is getting different.

The best solution over here is to run the server and request access using the same port. Since you running the nodejs server on port 63342 you need to access /login page with the domain

```
http://localhost:63342
```

Better still since the domain is the same you can avoid adding the domain and have the request as

```
function navbarformcontroller($scope,$http){
    $scope.user = {};

    $scope.loginuser = function(){
        console.log('entered');
        $http({
            method : 'POST' ,
            url : '/login',
            data : $scope.user
        })
            .success(function(data){
                alert(data);
            })
            .error(function(data, status){
                alert(data + " " + status + 'x');
            })
    };
}
```

Comment: actually i created two projects one is for client side and the other is for server side that is why the port numbers are different. Is there any way that How to create combine project for HTML 5 and NODEJS as same project so that i can run on the same port number ? The project has been created in the **Webstorm**

Comment: you can always do that....no need to have two separate folders....there is a public folder in nodejs where you can have all the client files and nodejs server can serve those files to the end user....the views can be in any template language as well...

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues here:

- It seems like you may not be using a body parsing middleware. If you're not dealing with files, you could probably just use the [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) module on npm. If you need `multipart/form-data` (file) support, there are links to modules that can handle these types of requests, in `body-parser`'s readme.
- You're trying to both render a template *and* the string "success" to the client simultaneously. Also, for template rendering it's `res.render()` not `req.render()`.
- You're attempting a cross-origin request. While the hostname may be the same, the ports are different and that also constitutes a cross-origin request. So one of the easiest ways to handle CORS in Express is to use a middleware such as [cors](https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors) on npm. If you need to send cookies, custom headers, etc. with the request, you'll need to set `withCredentials: true` in your `$http` config object.